# UITableView acting weird on storyboard builder

Tags: uitableview, nslayoutconstraint, xcode9.2

Is there anyone encounter this problem on Xcode 9.2?
[image]

I setup the UITableView as shown in the image above. And added a UILabel below the UITableView for demonstration. The image above is in "portrait" and the constraints work fine and ok.

[image]
When I change the orientation to "landscape" the constraints seems didn't work on the UITableViewCell although no errors is shown. While the UILabel below the table readjusted as expected it should be.

Anyone can explain this? and how could I possible fix this? It's kind of annoying...

Xcode version: 9.2

Comment: Please try using only 3 constraints, Leading space, trailing space and Align center Y to superview

Comment: tried it didn't work :(

Comment: any way can you please send me code? so I can do it for you and revert back

Comment: i created a dummy project with only storyboard, so there's no code. I'm not sure what you mean "code"

Comment: I'm not sure how can I send you the whole dummy project. BTW when I run the table works fine. The only problem is in the xCode where the UI of the UITableViewCell isn't redrawing when changing the orientation or device (iPad to iPhone)